# Rails testing with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am currently following a Rails tutorial from freeCodeCamp(https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/lets-create-an-intermediate-level-ruby-on-rails-application-d7c6e997c63f/) and am having some issues with the testing.  I'm using Rails 7 so expect some differences from the tutorial that have been solvable thus far but this one has me stumped.

In the case of testing a log out or viewing an individual post it the page.find(selector).click doesn't seem to trigger an event. So when the test clicks a post (or the user-menu that will display the logout button) Capybara can't find the selector.

One of the tests:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Visit single post", :type => :feature do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:post) { create(:post) }

  scenario "User goes to a single post from the home page", js: true do
    post
    visit root_path
    page.find(".single-post-card").click
    expect(page).to have_selector('body .modal')
    page.find('.interested a').click
    expect(page).to have_selector('#single-post-content p', text: post.content)
  end

end
```

and the error:

```
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector('body .modal')
       expected to find visible css "body .modal" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters. 
     # ./spec/features/posts/visit_single_post_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Seems like this is a known issue but the various solutions I've found online don't seem to help.

The page.find(".single-post-card") does return a Capybara element but won't find the next selector.
I'm using Ruby 3.2.2, Rails 7.0.5, Chrome 113, RSpec and the selenium-webdriver, webdrivers, capybara and poltergesit gems on an M1 Mac.

I have tried https://medium.com/@alieckaja/capybara-inconsistent-click-behavior-and-flickering-tests-f50b5fae8ab2

The page works fine when going through Chrome and manually testing the links while screenshots through Capybara's save_screenshot method confirm that the click isn't working in testing.

Comment: I've always had better success using an id e.g. '#single-post-card', because using a class as a selector may not be the element you're trying to target. Also, maybe your code is actually failing, so that the javascript (if you have it) that is supposed to respond is not doing so.

Comment: You could try disabling modal transitions, sometimes transitions take longer than the time Capybara waits for an element to appear. Also you could enable capybara-screenshot to check the elements of the DOM when the test failed.